# How can I know what packages can be upgraded to a new version given a composer.json file?

Tags: composer-php, packagist

Is there any utility or service that allows to know what packages have released new versions given a custom composer.json file?

It would be very useful in order to plan packages upgrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `composer show --outdated` to get the list of outdated packages.
Outdated are all packages, which have a newer version available or are abandoned/replaced by another package.

In case you want a full overview including outdated and up-to-date ones, then you can use `composer show --latest`.

For more: `composer show --help`.

Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show

---

Some repositories use external services like [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com/) to track, whether their dependencies are up to date. The status is often indicated by a "dependency up-to-date" badge, which is added to the readme of the project. You can find that for instance in the [Readme of the Yii2 Framework](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2#yii-php-framework-version-2).